# Prove that Cyclic Group with only one generator can have at most 2 element

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, cyclic-groups

I want someone to check my proof
Suppose the cyclic group with one generator can have more than 2 element
Consider 2 element since number of generator can't exceed number of element then it has 2 element.
But if it not,It must have <1> as generator and atleast

prime number as generator.That contradict
Therefore cyclic group with only one generator can have at most 2 element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $G$ such a Group with its unique generator $g\in G$. But then $g^n=e\iff \left(g^{-1}\right)^n=e$ thus $g^{-1}$ is also a generator. Can you take from here?

Comment: I can't .  I have I just started read abstract algebra I'm newbie in this field-*-

Comment: ok I get that now thank